# Collectors group by characteristic and minimum value of a field of said characteristic

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Title is sort of confusing but I'm not sure how to explain my problem in a simple sentence.

I have a homework task to group an arraylist of rectangles by length (same as perimeter in this case) using streams and collectors and to calculate minimum width for each group. I have tried the following:

```
public static Map<Double, Double> groupIndenticalPerimeterWidth(ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles){
        return rectangles.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Rectangle::getLength, Collectors.minBy((rectangle1, rectangle2) -> Double.compare(rectangle1.getWidth(), rectangle2.getWidth()))));
    }
```

which gets me a `Map<Double, Optional<Rectangle>>` and I can't figure out how to get the width of minimum rectangle in the second arguement of `Collectors.groupingBy` instead of `Optional<Rectangle>`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> group an arraylist of rectangles by `length` (same as **perimeter** in this case) using streams and collectors and to calculate **minimum** `width` for each group.

As you've noticed, *collector* `minBy()` produces `Optional<Rectangle>`.

To get double property from the optional result, you can use *collector* [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)). It expects a collector (`minBy()` in this case) as the first argument, and a *function* that transforms the result produced by the *collector* as the second argument.

```
public static Map<Double, Double> groupIndenticalPerimeterWidth(ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles){
    return rectangles.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Rectangle::getPerimeter,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Rectangle::getWidth)),
                result -> result.map(Rectangle::getWidth).orElseThrow() // `map` transforms Optional<Rectangle> into Optional<Double> and `orElseThrow` extracts the value from the optional
            )
        ));
}
```

Dummy `Rectangle` class:

```
public static class Rectangle {
    private double height;
    private double width;
    
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (height + width);
    }

    // getters
}
```

*Sidenote:* it's highly advisable to use Java 8 static methods when you need to define a compactor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `groupingBy` with the necessity to extract an Optional you can do it easier with `toMap` with a merge function:

```
 public static Map<Double, Double> groupIndenticalPerimeterWidth(List<Rectangle> rectangles) {
    return rectangles.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                           Rectangle::getPerimeter, Rectangle::getWidth, Math::min));
}
```